# How do i get data from database with php prepared statements like in my code and echo them out in a webpage?

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I'm trying to get out data in a page with a prepared statement. Is this code wrong or:`

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123456", "test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("error".mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query=" SELECT * FROM persons WHERE name=? AND last=? ;";
$stm=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(! mysqli_stmt_prepare($stm, $query)){
    echo "statment  failed";
}
else{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stm , "ss", $name , $last);
};

mysqli_stmt_execute($stm);
```

`

Comment: Have you tried to run in before asking?

Comment: yes i tryed pavel , modified the code but it doesn't work ! I can't echo the code out , or i make a mistake in code writing or in can't output the code in the index page

Comment: What are values oof $name and $last?

Comment: @vinay thoese actually should be the values of the variables wich i get from the Database.

Comment: @Vinay yes the variable that i want to get from the DB

Comment: you try my code in answer.

Comment: @Vinay yes i did it still doesn't give me any result , a questin by bind_params should they be i quotations ?

Comment: what error is showing?

Comment: @Vinay it doesn't show any error at all , it returns a emty array from the database , but now i think there is an error with xammp , beacuse in a login form i have also issues . Gona reinstalled it all over !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123456", "test");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("error".mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }

    $name = 'eliot';
    $last = 'carbone';

    $query=" SELECT * FROM persons WHERE name=? AND last=? ;"

    if($stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query)){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1,"ss", $name , $last);

        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1)){    

            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt1);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            $foundnum = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

            echo $name = $row['year'];

                }
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_stmt_execute($stm);    
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stm);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    var_dump($row); # your result
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stm);
mysqli_close($conn);
```